# My postgresql query is returning10 rows in terminal but postman is showing an error

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, postman, backend

this is how I query it on terminal

`SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE LOWER(display_name) LIKE LOWER('%');`

[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOdCP.png)

as you can see it's returning 10 rows but on postman it's returning this error message

[postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Q8H.png)

this is how I set it up on NodeJs

```
// Search single user
app.get("/api/v1/productly/user/search/:name", authorize, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await db.query(
      "SELECT user_id, display_name FROM users WHERE LOWER(display_name) LIKE LOWER('%')"
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      user_results: users.rows.length,
      data: {
        users: users.rows,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: { error } });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please don't use external images, or images at all. Plain text works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
   const userQuery = `SELECT user_id, display_name FROM users WHERE LOWER(display_name) LIKE LOWER('%');`
    const users = await db.query(userQuery,{type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT });

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      user_results: users.length,
      data: {
        users: users,
      },
    });
  }
```